# Symfony $form->save() inserts a row instead of updating it

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm trying to figure why my form tries to insert a row instead of updating it, but I have no clue, here's the code:

```
//This function is the one that displays the form
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {

...

    $evrescrit = new Criteria();
    $evrescrit->addSelectColumn(EvaluacionResumenPeer::STATUS);
    $evrescrit->addSelectColumn(EvaluacionResumenPeer::RELEVANCE);
    $evrescrit->addSelectColumn(EvaluacionResumenPeer::QUALITY);
    $evrescrit->addSelectColumn(EvaluacionResumenPeer::COMMENT);
    $evrescrit->add(EvaluacionResumenPeer::RESUMEN_ID, $this->resumen->getId());

    $this->form = new EvaluacionResumenForm(EvaluacionResumenPeer::retrieveByPK($this->resumen->getId()), array('criteria' => $evrescrit));
    //$this->form = new EvaluacionResumenForm(EvaluacionResumenPeer::retrieveByPK($this->resumen->getId()));
}


 //The form, I'm using the Base but unsetting some columns, PK and FK.
class EvaluacionResumenForm extends BaseEvaluacionResumenForm {

public function configure() {
    unset(
            $this['created_at'], $this['updated_at'], $this['evaluador_id'], $this['resumen_id']
    );
}

}


//This is where the form submits
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request) {

    $user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
    $this->forward404Unless($user);
    $this->form = new EvaluacionResumenForm();

    if ($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST)) {
        $this->processEdit($request, $this->form);
    }
}

public function processEdit(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form) {

    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()));
    //$this->form->bind($request->getPostParameter($request->getPostParameter('status')));

    $errors = $this->form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors();
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        foreach ($errors as $name => $error) {
            echo $name . ': ' . $error . '<br>';
            echo $request->getParameter('evaluacion_resumen[resumen_id]');
        }
    }

    if ($this->form->isValid()) {
        $this->form->save();
        $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'Sus modificaciones han sido grabadas.');
        $this->redirect('@resumenes_asignados');
    }
}
```

In the template I'm using this to render the form:

```
<?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(); ?>
<?php echo $form; ?>
```

The error I'm getting when I submit the form (I get the values from the database, and update them with this form) is this one:

```
Unable to execute INSERT statement. [wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`abstracts/evaluacion_resumen`, CONSTRAINT `evaluacion_resumen_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`resumen_id`) REFERENCES `resumen` (`id`))]
```

I really don't know why it tries to insert a new row, I need to update the existing one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the below piece of code in your `executeEdit()` function.

```
$this->form = new EvaluacionResumenForm();
```

`BaseEvaluacionResumenForm` inherits from `sfFormPropel`. `sfFormPropel` takes a Propel object as the first argument in its constructor. If no object is passed (as in your case), it will use the `getModelName()` function to determine which object in your model this form uses and create a new one (see below).

```
// \lib\vendor\....\sfFormPropel.class.php
public function __construct(BaseObject $object = null, $options = array(), $CSRFSecret = null)
  {
    $class = $this->getModelName();
    if (is_null($object))
    {
      $this->object = new $class();
    }
```

So when the form saves, it's saving a new object and that's why you're getting an insert instead of an update.

You want to do something like this:

```
// This is where the form submits
// Example url, http://mysite.com/moduleName/edit/id/:id
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request) {

    $user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
    $this->forward404Unless($user);

    // Get the primary key of the object we want to use or forward 404
    $this->forward404Unless($id = $request->getParameter('id'), "Required parameter 'id' must be present in request");

    // Retrieve the object from the database using the id or forward 404
    $this->forward404Unless($er = EvaluacionResumenPeer::retrieveByPK($id), sprintf("No object could be retrieved by %s", $id));

    $this->form = new EvaluacionResumenForm($er);

    if ($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST)) {
        $this->processEdit($request, $this->form);
    }
}
```

As an additional check you can change the type of request to PUT in your form template when the object is not new like below. This will make sure you don't accidentally insert any new objects in your edit action.

```
// apps\appName\modules\moduleName\templates\editSuccess.php
if (!$form->isNew()): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="PUT" />
<?php endif ?>
```

Then in your `executeEdit()` function. Change the line the checks if the request is of type POST to check if it's PUT.

```
if ($request->isMethod(sfRequest::PUT)) {
```